# jQuery-ui widget is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to check if a jQuery-ui widget is rendered or not (version 1.11.2)? To avoid `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on xxxx prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'xxxx'` errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the data api like

If your widget name is datepicker and the element id is `date` then

```
if($('#date').data('datepicker')){
    //call method since it is initialized
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xn27yjvp/)

---

The same can be done via the [:data()](http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/) selector

```
if ($('#date').is(':data(datepicker)')) {
    //call method since it is initialized
}
```